# module prestashop can not run file_get_contents

Tags: php, prestashop

I create module and using file_get_content function but can not success.

```
function openURL($url, $use_include_path = false, $stream_context = null, $curl_timeout = 500)
{
    if ($stream_context == null && preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $url)) {
        $stream_context = @stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => $curl_timeout)));
    }
    print_r($stream_context);
    if (in_array(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'), array('On', 'on', '1')) || !preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $url)) {
        return file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $stream_context);
    } elseif (function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $curl_timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        if ($stream_context != null) {
            $opts = stream_context_get_options($stream_context);
            if (isset($opts['http']['method']) && Tools::strtolower($opts['http']['method']) == 'post') {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                if (isset($opts['http']['content'])) {
                    parse_str($opts['http']['content'], $post_data);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
                }
            }
        }
        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $content;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is an error with filet_get_content function:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: follow this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710796/module-prestashop-can-not-run-file-get-contents/42718976#42718976

Answer (score 1):

It means your server cannot connect to the outside world

This probably won't change anything given the DNS issues

So, If you have permission, try changing the name servers in your /etc/resolv.conf file to other nameservers.

or

There should be as well httpd allowed to connect outside. Check you selinux policy. this helps me to solve connection problem:

`setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
 setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Answer (score 1):

You have to double check two things :

- Server (Firewall and DNS) configuration.
- Php configuration (maybe file_get_contents and curl are blocked)

Although, to respect Prestashop's standards, you should use Tools::file_get_contents(), which will wrap your request around a debugged function.

Comment: Thanks, It is DNS

Comment: You should check on Bind9 if your are on debian linux : https://wiki.debian.org/fr/Bind9
Or if you are behind something else (router ?), maybe Ufw, most common firewall on debian.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the url from which you are getting the content. May be targeted url is not working or not exist?